# Could EWS Managed API handle outlook form?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mapi

I have 2 questions below, could you help me?

1. Since **Exchange 2016** has dropped **MAPI/CDO**, and we’re suggested to use **EWS** instead.  I want to know, **could EWS can handle outlook form**, because we want to use EWS Managed API to install outlook form(we have created this form manually already) to user’s mailbox as a message. If not, is there any other recommend solution or SDK?
2. If we have a **.msg file**, could we use **EWS Managed API** to create a Email Message by using this .msg file on disk?

Thanks very much.  Hope for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2016 dropped support for the standalone version of MAPI/CDO 1.21. It still fully supports Outlook and RPC-over-HTPP and MAPI-over-HTTP.

I don't think you can either install a form or process an MSG file using EWS alone.